# Resample and resize numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I would like to resample a numpy array as suggested here [Resampling a numpy array representing an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242382/resampling-a-numpy-array-representing-an-image) however this resampling will do so by a factor i.e.

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
print scipy.ndimage.zoom(x, 2, order=1)
```

Will create a shape of (6,6) but how can I resample an array to its best approximation within a (4,6),(6,8) or (6,10) shape for instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing a single number to the `zoom` parameter, give a sequence:

```
scipy.ndimage.zoom(x, zoom=(1.5, 2.), order=1)
#array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
#       [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
#       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
#       [6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]])
```

With the sequences `(2., 2.75)` and `(2., 3.5)` you will get output arrays with shapes `(6, 8)` and `(6, 10)`, respectively.