# Opencv resize is different from my own manual calculation

Tags: python, image, opencv, resize

The Image array

```cpp
[[2, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 3, 3, 3],  
[2, 4, 4, 4],              
[5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

h = 4, w = 4
use `cv2.resize(img,(h//2,w//2))`, the result is

```cpp
[[2, 3],
[4, 5]]
```

The reduction factor is **2**, when I calculate manually,

```py
newImage(0,0) -> oldImage(2*0,2*0) = oldImage(0,0) = 2 
newImage(0,1) -> oldImage(2*0,2*1) = oldImage(0,2) = 2
newImage(1,0) -> oldImage(2*1,2*0) = oldImage(2,0) = 2
newImage(1,1) -> oldImage(2*1,2*1) = oldImage(2,2) = 4
```

The result of my manual calculation should be：

```cpp
[[2, 2],
[2, 4]]
```

I think my logic is not wrong ah, why would there be a difference with the opencv calculation it

Answer (score 3):

When resizing an image there are several interpolation methods. You select it with the `interpolation` parameter of `cv2.resize`.
This method determine how to calculate value for the new pixels based on the old ones.

The method which behaves similarly to the one you implemented manually is `cv.INTER_NEAREST`. For each destination pixel, it will select the source pixel closest to it and simply copy it's value, and the result will be like in your "manual" resize:

```
img2 = cv2.resize(img, (h//2, w//2), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Other interpolation methods like `cv2.INTER_LINEAR`, `cv.INTER_CUBIC` etc. perform a more sophisticated calculation, possibly taking into account several source pixels in the neighborhood of the destination pixel.

The default method in case you don't specify the `interpolation` parameter (like in your code above) is `cv2.INTER_LINEAR` (**not** `cv2.INTER_NEAREST`). This explains your result. You can set the `interpolation` parameter to different values and experiment.

See the documentation for `cv2.resize`:  [cv.resize](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d), and the list of interpolation methods:[InterpolationFlags](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121).

There are some rules of thumb which interpolation method performs the best for different scenarios. See here: [Which kind of interpolation best for resizing image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853632/which-kind-of-interpolation-best-for-resizing-image).