# Change image size using linear interpolation

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to change an image from lets say width=500 to width=100, using linear interpolation.
How can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `cv::resize` to resize the image. The `interpolation` parameter can be set to `cv::INTER_LINEAR` for linear interpolation.

Code example:

```
cv::Mat bigImg(cv::Size(500, 500), CV_8UC1);
// Initialize bigImg in some way ...
cv::Mat smallImg;
cv::resize(bigImg, smallImg, cv::Size(100, 100), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

See the documentation for [`cv::resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d), and [interpolation options](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121).

You can also see recommended interpolation method for various cases here: [Which kind of interpolation best for resizing image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853632/which-kind-of-interpolation-best-for-resizing-image).